# Is it possible to make a program that does not require focus?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5, focus

[image]

This zoom overlay, when interacted with, doesn't change the focus. Is there any way to replicate this mechanic using PyQt5?

Comment: Could you please clarify? Is that overlay part of the interface or is it some sort of "desktop-wide" popup? And where should the focus be kept?

Comment: It is a desktop-wide popup meaning it will appear everywhere. I would like the app I am making to not need focus at all, so when one clicks or interacts with it, it does not take focus away from the window which already has focus.

Comment: What OS is this aimed for?

Comment: @musicamante Windows and if possible, MacOS